# GTX 970 and GTX1080 non-SLI

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, windows

I'm attempting to run my Windows 10 Pro machine with both my 1080 and 970. As soon as I try to start blender I get the infamous "Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION". I've ran Blender with both cards indendently but never with them both installed on the machine. Is there some configuration change I have to make. I've done some trouble shooting.

1. Verified drivers are up to date.
2. Uninstalled Blender and deleted my %appdata%\Blender folder
3. Uninstalled video drivers and reinstalled them.

I'm at a loss but would really like the additional rendering capabilities under Cycles.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can solve this issue but I think it could be because the CUDA compute capability of each of these GPUs is different: [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)

Comment: Yah I was wondering if it was due to the CUDA capabilities of the card. They are a full generation of difference. Maybe time to get another 1080 or two.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, I currently have a GTX 580 paired with a 980ti both happily working with Blender with a far larger generation gap. I am under Windows 7 however, and i reckon Windows 10 is far pickier about card combinations, but if there were any issues I think they wouldn't be both recognized at OS level.

Comment: The card is recognized by Windows properly which is why I'm confused. Machine boots fine even. I've even ran advanced debugging it appears to attempt to load startup scene which for me is still stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after further investigation the issue was due to Duet Display software I was running on my desktop to use my iPad like a Cintiq. I'm going to reach out to Duet Display support and see if they have ever tested multiple video card configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because the CUDA compute capability of each of these GPUs is different: [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported)